# Get every first element from a list of lists

Tags: prolog

I have a list of lists `[[1,2,4],[5,6,7,8],[7,8,9]]`

I want to get every first element of the list, i.e. `[1,5,7]`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When asking questions here, please show what you have tried to solve it yourself. You can [edit] your question to include this.

Comment: Hint: use recursion. What is the base case - the head of an empty list of lists? What is the recursive case - when you have the rest of the heads of the lists, how would you go about getting the head of the first list and prepending it to that?

Comment: Or define a predicate that selects the first element of one list, then apply `maplist`. But as your post stands, it's unclear what you're asking. You need to ask a more specific question about the problem rather than "can someone help me?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution using [`maplist/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=maplist/3) and [`nth0/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=nth0/3):

```
first_of_each(List, Result) :- maplist(nth0(0), List, Result).
```

Here's a solution using recursion:

```
first_of_each([], []).
first_of_each([[First|_]|Xs], [First|Ys]) :- first_of_each(Xs, Ys).
```

Usage example:

```
?- first_of_each([[1,2,4],[5,6,7,8],[7,8,9]], Y).
Y = [1, 5, 7].
```